# Prove Lusin's Theorem with characteristic function and simple function.

Tags: measure-theory

**Lusin's Theorem**: Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable on $X$, $\mu(A)<\infty$, $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$ and $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists a $g \in C_c(X)$ such that $\mu ({x:f(x)\neq g(x)}) <\epsilon$.

In Rudin page 55-56, author proves with the general case of $f$.
Here, I want to prove theorem with $f$ is a **characteristic function**, $f$ is a **simple function** because Rudin's proof is long and complex.

Please hint me!
Thank you!